# forEach within ejs template is not defined

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, object

I have never used an ejs template before, and am relatively new to working with the front end.

My output is returning an object instead of an array, therefore I know `forEach` is not valid (currently getting an error that `forEach is not defined`, and that I should use `for..in` as an alternative.

Hoping someone can answer in what this would like using `for..in`

```
<% data.countries.forEach(function(country){ %>
    <div class="card">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h3>Country Name: <img alt="" src="<%=country.icon %>" /> <%= Country.name %></h3>
      <h5>Categories</h5>
      <ul>
       <% Country.categories.forEach(function(cat){ %>
        <li><%= cat.name %></li>
       <% }); %>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    <% }); %>
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the structure of your object and what output you would expect.

Comment: On the first or second forEach? Also, you have lowercase country as the forEach callback and are using uppercase Country elsewhere. Typo or different object?